# Is there a way to pattern match against value in the middle of a list? or at the end?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

something like

```
getFirstError :: [Either a b] -> a
getFirstError (x:y:...:Left w:z) = w
```

wrt Haskell but it might be interesting to know how other languages with pattern matching accomplish this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, despite the other answers, do this using view patterns extension in GHC:

```
   getFirstError ((msum . map test) -> Just x) = x
        where test (Left x) = Just x
              test (Right x) = Nothing
```

Alternatively using pattern guards:

```
   getFirstError (xs) | Just x <- (msum $ map test xs) = x
        where test (Left x) = Just x
              test (Right) x = Nothing
```

Comment: Did you accidentally omit the match on the `Just` constructor in the pattern-guards version?

Comment: Also, you require `Monoid` instance for the error type, which does not seem reasonable, and the `test` function does not compile because it does not have enough parentheses. And you return the concatenation of all errors instead of the first error.

Comment: Replacing `mconcat . map test -> Just x` with `mconcat . map (First . test) -> First (Just x)` should do the trick.

Comment: Wouldn't using `mapMaybe test` or just `fst . partitionEithers` be nicer anyway?

Comment: I fixed the syntactic issues, and I changed it to use a `MonadPlus` rather than a `Monoid`, which I believe should have the desired effect now.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can use a list comprehension

```
getFirstError xs = head [ x | Left x <- xs ]
```

Note that `head` will fail if there are no errors.

Comment: And `head` failing is itself an error of a different variety, so you could say that this function always finds *some* error, one way or another!

Answer (score 1):

No, there's not. However, you can easiliy write the function using recursion:

```
getFirstError [] = error "getFirstError: empty list or no error"
getFirstError (Left x : xs) = x
getFirstError (_ : xs) = getFirstError xs
```